# button group wraps label at full width bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have run into an issue I hope you can help solve.

I have a button group which when the browser expanded 100% wraps around the label.  What is the best method to stop this happening.  As I do not want the button group wrapping the label.

see html below.

```
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="selectme" class="form-control-label">add and remove me</label>
                                         <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                                        <input name="selectme" id="selectme" placeholder="add and remove me" class="form-control" type="text">
                                       <button onclick="addItem()" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add
                                    </button>
                                    <button onclick="removeItem()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Remove
                                    </button>
                                      </div>
                                        <ul class="list-group" id="my-list">
                                        </ul>
                                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does simply adding `<br>` after your input solve your issue? like this:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="selectme" class="form-control-label">add and remove me</label>
                                         <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                                        <input name="selectme" id="selectme" placeholder="add and remove me" class="form-control" type="text"><br>
                                       <button onclick="addItem()" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add
                                    </button>
                                    <button onclick="removeItem()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> Remove
                                    </button>
                                      </div>
                                        <ul class="list-group" id="my-list">
                                        </ul>
                                      </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this does not work.  I imaging it has to do with the btn-group behaviour.

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of the issue? Maybe I don't understand.  Also some CSS code would help.